# Delete all divIcon's from leaflet map then recover them

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to remove all the divIcon's from the map when zoom level < 16,

```
    <MapContainer className="leaflet-map" center={[latitude, longitude]}
        zoom={17} scrollWheelZoom={false}
        whenCreated={(map) => this.setState({ map })}>
        <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
    </MapContainer>
```

I tried `map._panes.markerPane.remove();` but I couldn't add another markers after they deleted

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    const { map } = this.state;

    map.on('zoomend', function () {
        var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
        if (currentZoom < 16) {
            //map._panes.markerPane.remove();
        } else {
                    L.marker(latitude, longitude], {
                        icon: new L.DivIcon({
                            className: 'my-div-icon',
                            iconSize: [5, 5],
                            html: '<p class="my-div-span">' + name + '</p>'
                        })
                    })
                        .addTo(map);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I do not fully understand how you are adding the markers and where do you get latitude, longitude and name you have to store the markers in an array and then remove them from the map using the map references.
So if we take into account that when zooming into a map level equal or more to 16, otherwise you are going to duplicate the same marker with the same text and the text is going to become bold if the same is added multiple times, you should do something similar to this:

```
const markers = []; // here define an empty array
    
class Map extends Component {
      state = { map: null };
    
      componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const { map } = this.state;
        map.on("zoomend", function () {
            var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
            console.log(currentZoom);
            if (currentZoom < 16) {
              markers.forEach((marker) => map.removeLayer(marker));
            } else {
              const marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude], {
                icon: new L.DivIcon({
                  className: "my-div-icon",
                  iconSize: [5, 5],
                  html: '<p class="my-div-span">' + name + "</p>"
                })
              });
              markers.push(marker);
              marker.addTo(map);
            }
        });
      }
   ...
 }
```

if marker is lower than 16 remove all the stored markers, otherwise add them both on map and on markers array.